# algorithm for filter relevant documents

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have two `unordered_map` hash tables.
One is `map1` `unordered_map<user_id, set<doc_id> >` that has about 3 million items and stores all documents user have read.
One is `map2` `unordered_map<user_id, map<user_id, relevant_score> >` that has about 1 million items and stores user's relevant user and their relevant score.
Now I want to get `map3` `unorderd_map<user_id, map<doc_id, relevant_score> >`.
For each `doc_id` in `map3`, it is calculated from `map2` and `map1`. e.g.
`map1` has `101` => `set{001, 002, 003}`
     `102` => `set{002, 003, 004}`
`map2` has `100` => `map{(101, 0.5), (102, 0.6)}` then
`map3` will be `100` => `map{(002, (0.5 + 0.6) / 2 = 0.55), (003, 0.55)}` because
`002` and `003` have been read by more than one user, so they will insert into `map3`. Any good algorithm for this situation or any thoughts on writing an efficient one?

Comment: Just for the sake of curiosity have you implemented `map1` and `map2` as you said? Too much memory is being used, and now `map3`.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni Any suggestions if I don't use `unorder_map` and keep time complexity low?

Comment: Use of `unordered_map` is helping you with time complexity. Use `unordered_map` in `map2` and `map3` for value part.More than the time complexity part, I felt worried about the memory being used. May be you could use a database but that will trade-off some time for memory. I will be happy if someone puts light over the memory usage, if not as a part of answer but at least as a comment.

Comment: @ShridharR.Kulkarni I can not use database, I get enough memory and just sacrifice it. :D

Comment: Your logic doesn't make sense to me. The ratings in `map2` are for users, not for documents. Then how do you proceed to create the sub-map of `map3` as a map of ratings for documents?

Comment: @nakiya The situation is that people may have same read hobbit, `map2` is for user who has same hobbit with him. `map3` is calculated from `map1` and `map2` containing documents that user in `map2` may be interested in.

Comment: @Howard : If that's the case, `map2` should be of the type `unordered_map<doc_id, map<user_id, relevant_score> >` shouldn't it?
(Or, `unordered_map<user_id, map<doc_id, relevant_score> >`)    Right now there's no `doc_id` in `map2`

Comment: @nakiya `unordered_map<user_id, map<user_id, relevant_score> >` is that I have. `unordered_map<user_id, map<doc_id, relevant_score> >` is to be calculated. I think I know how to solve this problem. :D

Comment: @Howard : But I still don't see how you can calculate averaged score for docs if you don't have individual score for docs in the first place. 

Perhaps you want to clarify the problem for yourself first. Good luck!